# Phonegap - Share functionality to Email, Twitter and Facebook

Tags: twitter, cordova

Is there an example how to program the functionality with the Phonegap Framework to share a URL to email, twitter and Facebook? For Example in Android this functionality is in 90% of the apps. In Iphone it is in any Apps. In the app of techcrunch for Iphone you can see it, when You open an article. Is it possible to create this with Phonegap too?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, looking for a simple solution that works for ios/phonegap (cordova 1.7)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in Android with the following code for a plugin. I haven't published this anywhere else yet, but eventually I hope to add it as a plugin in the phonegap plugin repository for Android.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var Share = function() {};

Share.prototype.show = function(content) {
    return PhoneGap.exec(
    function(args) {
        console.log("phonegap share plugin - success!")
    }, function(args) {
        console.log("phonegap share plugin - failed")
    }, 'Share', '', content);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin('share', new Share());
    PluginManager.addService("Share","com.COMPANYNAME(CHANGEME).android.plugins.Share");
});
```

JAVA IN ANDROID:

```
package com.COMPANYNAME(CHANGEME).android.plugins;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;

public class Share extends Plugin {
    private String callback;

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult mPlugin = null;
        try {
            mPlugin = activateSharing(args.getString(0), args.getString(1));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Exception", e.toString());
        }
        mPlugin.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.callback = callbackId;
        return mPlugin;
    }

    private PluginResult activateSharing(String title, String body) {
        final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Almost three years later: Here's a plugin that allows sharing on Android and iOS with the same API. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

It's available on PhoneGap Build as well!

Example

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Google is awesome, WOOT!', 'Google facts', 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png', 'http://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Login Facebook and post feed, login twitter and post status using plugin appInBrowser:

https://github.com/raulduran/facebook-twitter-cordova.git