# Android browser share link to phonegap app

Tags: android, phonegap-build

I'm developing a phongap build app.
I need that my app appear in the share menu of the android browser.
I've see this [Make Android app listen to shared links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624315/make-android-app-listen-to-shared-links) but i'm on phonegap-build and i don't have the manifest...
There is a way to do this? I need also to handle the relative call to my app :)

Thank you all

Tommaso

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how works phonegap but if you've an Activity, then you can use the following code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "A text to share");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via"));
```

Check [Android's documentation for sending content to other apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

[Here in method `shareList`](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/magicAnnotator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nbempire/android/magicannotator/component/activity/annotator/MarketAnnotatorActivity.java) (in line 406) you've got a working example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i don't know how to use your info with phonegap.

Comment: It's ok! Have you checked this answer here in SO? [phonegap-share-functionality-to-email-twitter-and-facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570701/phonegap-share-functionality-to-email-twitter-and-facebook); And check [this link](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/5/1/Example-of-Intents-with-PhoneGap) too

Comment: I think the OP wants his app to RECEIVE a share intent, not send it? (actually, I'm looking for this also :D)

Comment: Oh, in that case then what both of you need is [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) (may be there is something useful that you can use in PhoneGap too)